# TypeScript - type annotation for NodeJS module

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

In the NodeJS project I'm working on right now we use dependency injection, and along with instances of custom-written classes we used to pass modules like `fs`, `crypto`, `http` and others as an argument into constructor.

Now we would like to use TypeScript with [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) library to support NodeJS types. In case of NodeJS modules, it is not clear for me how can I describe the type definition for modules in TypeScript?

Example:

```
class ReportWriter {
    private fs: ???;
    constructor (fs: ???) { //what should I use instead of ???
        this.fs = fs;
    }
}
```

I can create a type alias like (or maybe an interface):

```
type NodeFsModule = { 
    readFile: Function, 
    readFileSync: Function 
};
```

But it requires me to describe a huge amount of functions. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `import` with `typeof`:

```
import fs = require('fs');
class ReportWriter {
    private fs: typeof fs;
    constructor (fs: typeof fs) {
        this.fs = fs;
    }
}
```

More here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html